# jmeter - able to render PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, jmeter

Is there an add-on or a config setting that will allow Jmeter to Render PDF output?

I am testing a web tool that exports report data to various outputs (excel, pdf, csv, etc.) and would love to setup an assertion to verify all outputs return the same value. The hitch is that Jmeter can't render pdf.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get at the code that writes to a graphics context, publishing the result to PDF is pretty straightforward using [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/)

Here's an example:  [Content from Graphics2D](http://1t3xt.info/examples/browse/?page=example&id=187)

Comment: Thanks - as soon as I can try hooking it into Jmeter, I'll let you know how it works.